# aspx page error passing stored procedure(sql) ASP.NET (C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio, stored-procedures

I'm new to asp programming. I was using direct SQL commands in this page and the program was running properly but when I changed the commands to stored procedures and defined them as follows the error came as stated below.

ASPX markup:

```
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourceTech" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:constr %>" 
        SelectCommand="usp_get_technical_data"
        UpdateCommand="usp_update_technical_data" 
        SelectCommandType = "StoredProcedure" 
        UpdateCommandType ="StoredProcedure">

        <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="LblTowerNo" Name="tower" PropertyName = "Text" Type = "String"/>
           </SelectParameters>
        <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="type" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="extension" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="insulator" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="aviation_lamp" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="pilot" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="t_start" Type="DateTime" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="t_complete" Type="DateTime" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="tower" Type="String" />
        </UpdateParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

The error:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Parser Error
>
> Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: The server tag is not well formed.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 142: asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourceSpan" runat="server"

Comment: I think you forgot to put the error detail in your question.

Comment: i think theres something wrong with the syntax in "<asp:..........>" tag. idk im not getting it

Comment: Separately..it is working code..please provide upper lower code of this code block

Comment: the upper and lower parts of the code isn't relevant. They are in different context.

Comment: the code is working with direct sql commands like a charm. when changed to stored procedure...do we have to define the stored procedure elsewhere too apart from what i have already done ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check the line :

```
ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:constr %>"
```

and if the ConnectionString inside has double quotes, try use single quotes for param like :

```
ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:constr %>'
```

Eventually again, carefully check the before/after code around the post code.

Comment: ok, try check storedprocedure number of parameters and post there the work code with direct sql commands.